# Unity3D сериализация Scriptable Object

Tags: unity3d

У игры порой сбрасываются сохранения, я думаю это связанно с изменением instanceID, который уникален, но не постоянен. Вот фрагмент из сохраненного JSON файла.

```
"boughtSpells":[{"instanceID":13864},{"instanceID":13421}]
```

Сам Scriptable Object, который нужно сериализовать

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Spell Pattern", menuName = "SpellPattern")]
[System.Serializable]
public class SpellPattern : ScriptableObject {
    public string spellName;

    [TextArea]
    public string spellDescription;
}
```

Сейв игры

```
[Serializable]
public class GameData
{
    public List<SpellPattern> boughtSpells;
}
```

Я думаю, что оно сохраняет ссылку на ID объекта Unity, а не сериализует каждый тип данных. Как правильно сериализовать класс SpellPattern, что бы в сохранённом файле была не ссылка, а нужные данные?

Comment: Свой сериализатор написать)